# In C++, is it possible to get the return type of a function in order to declare a variable without calling that function?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int myfun()
{
  return 42;
}
```

I know I can write

```
auto myvar = myfun();
```

but what if I just want to declare `myvar` (without using a common `typedef`)?

```
the_type_returned_by_myfun myvar;
```

What can be written instead of `the_type_returned_by_myfun`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `decltype`.

```
decltype(myfun()) myvar;
// or
typedef decltype(myfun()) myfun_ret;
myfun_ret myvar2;
```

And if the function happens to have parameters, you can produce fake parameters with `std::declval`.

```
#include <utility>

int my_other_fun(foo f);
typedef decltype(myfun(std::declval<foo>())) my_other_fun;
```

Answer (score 9):

decltype is your friend:

```
decltype(myfun()) myvar;
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the job of `decltype`:

```
decltype(myfun()) myvar;
```